# sql query don't pick the value

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have simple SQL insert query:

```
INSERT INTO db_name (COL1, COL2, COL3, ...) 
VALUES ('value1', (SELECT name FROM another_table WHERE id = :php_value), value3 .....)
```

But sometimes `COL2` value is NULL because `SELECT` don't pick nothing (name exist) is it possible to protect from empty records? Or I need change script and keep select before insert (outside insert)?
That's happen not regularly but ~1/3000 records

Comment: I don't think I got it all right, but maybe you can try with isnull() or coalesce()

Comment: your value of `COL3` is `value3`  which is not part of your `SELECT`.

Comment: @ughai my fault I mean col2 sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with condition `id = :php_value` the query doesn't sometimes return data. You can avoid insert row to the table with empty `name` this way:

```
INSERT INTO db_name (COL1, COL2, COL3, ...) 
SELECT 'value1', name, 'value3',... 
FROM another_table 
WHERE id = :php_value
```

Comment: but another_table 100% have that value. Maybe server lag or delays?

Comment: @Klapsius I don't know your environment so I can't tell anything about it. I can base only on your question so I can tell that condition `id = :php_value` sometimes doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using PHP.
You can just initialize the name variable with a default value and then run the select query separately.

```
$name = ""; // or whatever you want the default value to be
$query = "SELECT `name` FROM `another_table` WHERE `id` = '" + php_value + "'";
```

You can now get the name from the query and store it in the $name variable (you can first check whether the value returned by the database isn't null).

Then you can create the next query and run it embedding the $name variable.